# Pasar parametros en request GET en API Gateway para usarlos en función lambda

Tags: nodejs, aws, nosql

Actualmente tengo la siguiente función lambda en la que obtiene todos los datos de una tabla `Users` de DynamoDB

```js
function response(statusCode, message) {
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(message)
  };
}

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // manually id:
    const id = 2
    let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            UserId: id
        },
        TableName: 'Users'
    }

     return docClient
    .get(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then((res) => {
      if (res) callback(null, response(res.Item));
      else callback(null, response(404, { error: 'Post not found' }));
    })
    .catch((err) => callback(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
    
}
```

En este ejemplo Mi objetivo es obtener el resultado la columna sites de la tabla Users para el usuario 2: `[{"UserId":2,"sites":["Barcelona","Venecia","Paris","Madrid"],"username":"Pedro"}]`

Mi pregunta es, en vez de que este escrito manualmente el id, como lo puedo pasar el los parámetros como request GET usando API Gateway, y luego colocarlo en esta función lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar, deberías usar el método `Post`, sino no podrás pasarle parámetros por *API Gateway*, en el `body` de tu `request` envíale los datos que necesitas en formato *Json* y luego en el handler del lambda capturas este valor.

Yo realizo algo parecido pero en netcore:

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
```

Como ves en mi *handler* le envio el `string` input y ahi es donde recibo el valor que deseo recibir desde el *API Gateway*